# Laptop fan possibly not working, unsure

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan

So, I have a Lenovo G550. I've had a few issues concerning the fan. Well, I think so.

I have no way to open the laptop at the moment. I'm running XUbuntu 14.04.

Anyways. I've noticed the laptop has been getting quite close, the cpu, to 105 C which `sensors` says is the max temp for the processor.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
  temp1:        +104.0°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
  Core 0:       +103.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
  Core 1:       +102.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
  fan1:           0 RPM
```

When I check the fan, looking threw the vents, it does ***not*** appear to be moving, I hear a faint noise coming from the vent but at the time I believe that's just the HDD. At times when it gets ***really*** close to 105.0 the laptop becomes sluggish.

I've never had any issues like this before, and the laptop is from 2009 so I'm wondering if maybe the compound may be off? I'm not sure. Anyways, This is my only working computer I have and I really don't want it to be unusable at any point, so any indication of what might be wrong would be helpful.

I most recently cleaned out the computer interior around a month ago.

With thinkpad_acpi enabled
`more /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` reports

```
status:     enabled
speed:      0
level:      7
```

Comment: Have you ever opened the computer and cleaned it out? If yes, then when was the last time?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I cleaned it out around a month ago.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include additional information in response to comments, then use a comment to draw the requester's attention to the edit if appropriate. I've edited the information in; feel free to edit further if that's not exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly, you need acquire some basic tools to crack open that case and have a basic multi-meter and little wire leads on hand to perform a couple tests.

Test...:

1. ...with the computer on, for voltage at fan; should read well above 0 volts but voltage could be low if the fan is suppose to be running at a low speed.
2. ...That fan works; find 5 volts on your motherboard, then wire in 5 volts to the fan from anywhere you can find the voltage

It could be a software based problem as well, but highly unlikely.